# Creating new column from filtering others

Tags: python, pandas

I need to assign to a new column the value 1 or 0 depending on what other columns have.
I have around 30 columns with binary values (1 or 0), but also other variables with numeric, continuous, values (e.g. 200). I would like to avoid the write a logical condition with many OR, so I was wondering if there is an easy and fast way to do it.
For example, creating a list with name of columns and assign 1 to the new column if there is at least a value 1 across all the columns for that corresponding row.

Example:

```
a1 b1 d4    ....
1   0  1
0   0  1
0   0  0
...
```

Expected:

```
a1 b1 d4    .... New  
1   0  1          1
0   0  1          1
0   0  0          0
...
```

Many thanks  for your help

Comment: `df['New'] = df.max(1)`.

Comment: thanks Quang Hoang, but it gives me the maximum from other columns in the dataframe as well

Comment: ```df['New'] = df[[bin_col1, binary_col2, ...]].max(1)``` can you try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a1':[1,0,0,1], 'b1':[0,0,0,1], 'd4':[1,1,0,0], 'num':[12,-2,0,3]})
df['New'] = df[['a1','b1','d4']].any(1).astype('int')
df

    a1  b1  d4  num New
0   1   0   1   12  1
1   0   0   1   -2  1
2   0   0   0   0   0
3   1   1   0   3   1
```